# How can I click "invisible" reCAPTCHA buttons using Selenium web automation?

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation, recaptcha

I am using Python and Selenium to automate this website: https://prenotami.esteri.it

The script I made fills out a form and then clicks a button to advance to the next page. These actions are carried out using Selenium's *find_element_by_xpath()* function. Recently, the website added a reCAPTCHA that pops up after the button is clicked, and must be completed before advancing.

I have already written a Python script that is capable of surpassing this type of captchas by using the audio option. However, in this particular website, I am not able to find the xpath to the audio button of the reCAPTCHA. Although there is an iframe that contains the reCAPTCHA, there seems not to be anything inside it.

[image: Website I am trying to automate]

In the first attached image you can see how this website's reCAPTCHA looks like in HTML, compared to other website that is visible in the second image, where a *#document* can be seen inside the iframe.

[image: Other website example]

My intention is to run this program using headless Chrome, so I can't relay in any mouse control functions offered by pyautogui for example.

I've been scratching my head around this problem for a while, so any advice is useful. Thanks!

**Edit:** after some research I have found that this type of reCAPTCHA that doesn't need to check a "I am not a robot" checkbox is called "invisible reCAPTCHA". The captcha only pops up if the detected activity is suspicious (for example clicking too fast). I have tried adding random waits and movements to mimic human behaviour, but the captcha still appears after some tries. Since I don't think there is a way to avoid the captcha from appearing 100% of the times, the question of how to click the buttons using Selenium's *find_element_by_xpath()* function remains the same. Leaving this as a note just in case someone finds it useful.

Comment: I'm looking to automate the same website (not the Argentian version, but the Brazilian one). Did you succeed doing it?

Comment: I still haven't had the time to continue with this project, but I've tried the accepted solution in order to interact with the captcha and it works fine. If you use this in addition with a VPN, you should be able to automate it.

Comment: @LM2000 so did you solve this problem? Currently I can get captcha token and inputted in textarea, but there is no action. how can I submit it using captcha token(it will be get using python-capmonster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever tried to use the following function:

```
add_argument("-auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
```

I managed to interact with captcha

Answer (score 0):

If the position is always fixed, you can use [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to move the mouse and click on it

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.click(100, 100) # button coordinates
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my original question:

_"My intention is to run this program using headless Chrome, so I can't relay in any mouse control functions offered by pyautogui for example."_

So yeah, I am aware that this solution exists but it is not useful for my case. Thank you anyways.

Comment: @LisandroMarinelli are you sure about the fact that the iframe is empty? On the screenshot, you haven't exploded it

Comment: yeah, there is only an _</iframe>_ inside. I have updated the image anyways to avoid confusion. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since, it is in iframe, we need to move our selenium pointing to iframe and then use your xpath.

```
driver.switch_to.frame("c-la7g7xqfbit4")
capchaBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@id='recaptcha-audio-button'])[2]")
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. This method will work in most websites that use a "normal" reCAPTCHA (second image), but it doesn't work in the ones that use an "invisible" reCAPTCHA (first image), like the one I am trying to automate. Although the recaptcha audio button can be seen, I can't find it anywhere inside the HTML code. Also, as a side note, because the iframe name changes each time the page is loaded, the correct way to do it is to use `driver.switch_to.frame(n)` where n is the iframe number.

Comment: There is another solution for this. We can get element based on tag names. Then switch to the iframe and click them. Ref this link-- 
 https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I believe that you are not fully understanding my problem.  I have already located the captcha iframe, and I know how to switch to that specific iframe. The problem is that the iframe is empty, there are no elements inside it. So I can't get the recaptcha-audio-button tag because, although it is visible and clickeable, it just does not exist in the HTML code.

Comment: last one suggestion, can you add time delay, because we will get no such element exception if we try before page constructs

Comment: There is a `time.sleep()` already implemented to make sure the website loads everything.